Building iOS app from GitHub workflow without Expo Cloud: Is this possible?
I’m trying to set up a GitHub workflow to build my iOS app without relying on Expo Cloud. Here’s the command I’m running:
eas build --platform ios --local --non-interactive --output /home/runner/work/rn-hello-world/rn-hello-world/app-release.ipa

But I’m running into this error:
Unsupported platform, macOS is required to build apps for iOS
    Error: build command failed.

Is there a way to make this work, or am I forced to use macOS or Expo Cloud for iOS builds? I’d appreciate any advice on how others might be handling local iOS builds in CI environments without a macOS machine.
